# Making jQuery Fadeout() callback function synchronous

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do something like this

```
01 ...do some heavy duty stuff

02   //delete some rows <tr>
03 $('...').fadeOut(function () {
04     $(this).remove();
05 }); 

06 ...do some heavy duty stuff
07 ...add some rows <tr>
```

However the fadeOut's call back function doesn't get fire immediately. Because of this my logic of adding new rows after removing them does not work properly. I know I can place the code at line 6 and 7 inside the callback but I don't want to do this because the callback has alot of logic and gets called from other places.

Is there a way I can force fadeout() to complete executing its callback before it reaches line 6?

Answer (score 2):

No, and even if there was a way, it'd be a bad idea as it'd block many browser from updating its GUI completely, making it hang.

If you have a common callback in the fadeOut function that is used in many places (let's call this `commonCallback`), all you need to do is wrap it inside another function:

```
// ...do some heavy duty stuff

//delete some rows <tr>
$('...').fadeOut(function () {
    commonCallback();

    // ...do some heavy duty stuff
    // ...add some rows <tr>
});
```

Comment: Anything inside the callback will get executed once for *each* item getting the `fadeOut`. This is probably not desired.

Comment: This would not solve the issue of making it synchronous, it only solves reusability.

Comment: Yes it would, the "do some heavy duty stuff" would *not* be executed before `commonCallback` does its job. The trick to solving the synchronicity issue was to move the code inside the fadeOut callback, and the original common fadeOut callback code was moved to its own function so it can be reused easily.

Answer (score 2):

One safe option would be to use a `setTimeout()` with the duration set to the same as the `fadeOut()`.

```
$('...').fadeOut(function () {
     $(this).remove();
}, 600); 

setTimeout(function() {
    // place your code that should wait
    //   for the fadeOut to complete
    //   inside here
}, 600);
```

Note that the duration for both are set to the same `600ms` duration.

Any code you plase inside the `setTimeout` function will wait `600ms` to execute *without* freezing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set a flag? I don't think that's a good option but it may work.

What might be more important is the structure of your code. Not everything needs to be anonymous. Even if the callback is complex you can still organize your code so that moving lines 6 and 7 into the callback is easy. For example:

```
$('...').fadeOut(function() {
   doRemoveAndLotsOfCoolStuff();
   doLines6and7();
});
```